# Wrong output after removing character from string

Tags: c++

I have the following code to remove all vowels in a string:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    bool checkVowels(char s);
    int main()
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)

        {

            if (checkVowels(s[i]))
                s.erase(i,1);
        }
        cout << s;
        return 0;
    }
    

    bool checkVowels(char s)
    {

        return s =='a' || s =='e' || s =='i' || s=='o' || s =='u'
            || s =='A' || s =='E' || s =='I' || s =='O'|| s =='U';
    }
```

When I input "tour", my expected outcome is "tr", but the actual outcome is "tur". Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Think about what happens to the remaining characters of the string when you remove one letter and how your indexing should adjust for that

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That should make it very clear what the problem is.

Comment: when i=0, you check `t`, when i=1 you check `o` and remove it, when i=2 you check `r` ... `u` is never checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that checking and modifying the string while iterating on its size might be the problem here.
After each `erase`, the string indexes/character are "moved" down, so when the next loop iteration start, the next character is not checked.
Might want to use a temporary string to hold "non vowel" characters, but it might not be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

All the commenters pointed out the problem correctly: you are erasing while iterating and this way you break the loop condition (`s.size()` is different).

I recommend to start thinking in terms of algorithms, not in terms of loops.

In C++11 and above you can use the `std::stable_partition` algorithm to move all the non-vowels to the beginning of the string without breaking the order and then "cut-off" the vowels with `s.resize`. This is more effective than throwing away symbols as you go.

Here is the full sample:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// I have inverted the condition - otherwise all non-vowels get deleted
bool isNotVowel(char s)
{
    return s !='a' && s !='e' && s !='i' && s !='o' && s !='u'
        && s !='A' && s !='E' && s !='I' && s !='O' && s !='U';
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    // C++20 variant, using checkVowels:
    // std::erase_if(s.begin(), s.end(), checkVowels);

    // move all vowels to the back of the string, cut off the last part
    s.resize(
         std::distance(s.begin(),
                       std::stable_partition(
                           s.begin(), s.end(), isNotVowel)));

    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

The above approach requires no reallocations and O(N*log(N)) swaps  of the characters. Then `resize` simply decreases the internal counter, which is an O(1)-operation.

In C++20, using `std::erase_if` your problem also becomes an even shorter one-liner:

```
std::erase_if(s.begin(), s.end(), checkVowels);
```

If you still want the "good old loop", then do it in a straightforward way:

```
std::string out_s;
// for non-C++11 use just the
// for (int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++)
for (const auto& ch: s)
    if (!checkVowels(ch))
        out_s += ch;
s = out_s;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of testing for errors in loops is to print a partial result from every iteration. In this case you could use something like this at the very beginning of your loop:

```
cout << "iteration: ";
cout << i;
cout << ", letter: ";
cout << s[i];
cout << "\n";
```

This would print out:

```
iteration: 0, letter: t
iteration: 1, letter: o
iteration: 2, letter: r
tur
```

So the issue is  that when you remove the second letter "o" from the string "tour", the length of the string changes, therefore on the third iteration the program checks the third letter of your new string "tur". The same problem appears with all strings that have two or more vowels in a row. In other words, the letter after a vowel is skipped and never checked.

A rather inelegant fix would be to subtract 1 from i every time a vowel is removed, so that letters after vowels are checked:

```
if (checkVowels(s[i]))
{
    s.erase(i,1);
    i--;
}
```

This doesn't change your code much, but it's not good practice.

It would be better to use a separate variable for storing the output string, instead of modifying `s` directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool checkVowels(char s);
int main()
{
    string s;
    string s_out;
    cin >> s;
    

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)

    {
    
        if (!checkVowels(s[i]))
        {
            s_out += s[i];
        }
    }
    cout << s_out;
    return 0;
}


bool checkVowels(char s)
{

    return s =='a' || s =='e' || s =='i' || s=='o' || s =='u'
        || s =='A' || s =='E' || s =='I' || s =='O'|| s =='U';
}
```